# Is it possible to filter emails from addresses starting with something?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, search, gmail-search

I deal with a public institution that sends emails from a variety of addresses such as `portaligi1001@gmail.com`, `portaligi1002@gmail.com`, etc. To my absolute dismay, when I type `portaligi` in my Gmail, I only get a few results that actually contain the string `portaligi` in the body of the email. I have many dozens of emails from them. I also tried searches like `from:portaligi*` but this syntax doesn't work, I get no results. Is there any way I can filter all the emails sent by an address starting with `portaligi`?

Comment: Do they also vary the sender name?  That is more forgiving of portions.  PS asterisk * is meaningless in Gmail searches

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do this in normal Gmail. You could access your Gmail over IMAP and use the client (eg thunderbird) for this.

Alternatively you may be able to create rules to label these mails on arrival & use the label to search for them.